# Combining two different selector value in Jsoup at same time

Tags: java, jsoup

[image]

As shown in image....

This is my HTML table tag.

What I want to do is to combine two **TD** values i.e. **1016 TERRACE DR** and **NAPA CA 94559** from two different **TR** shown in Red box at same time means using only single selector syntax.

I am getting both values seperatly but want to get them at the same time..

Can you please suggest How can I do this?

I have used selector Syntax for Getting Entity Address as

`td:contains(Entity Address) ~ td`

and for Accessing Entity City, State, Zip I have used

```
td:contains(Entity City, State) ~ td
```

Both works well when I used them individually but my requirement is to get them at the same time.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use them in one line by separating it with `,`:

```
td:contains(Entity Address) ~ td, td:contains(Entity City, State) ~ td
```

This selects an element that matches one of both.